# Is there something in Illustrator that resembles tabs/tab-stops in MS Word?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I'm using Illustrator (CS5) to create a menu for a restaurant.

In a word doc, I have a tab at the end of a textcolumn. It's a 'right'-aligned tabstop. So my text resembles this:

```
food                    100 $
wine                100.000 $
happiness                42 $
```

Pretty basic. How do I get this in Illustrator?

Right now I have a word document that I want to copy in Illustrator since I want to step up my game. I know how to work with Illustrator, the basics, but not much about text-aligning/layouting.

I know that it's not a bad idea to use inDesign but I neither possess the skill nor the software. It would surprise me if this is not possible in Illustrator.
If there are any obvious/easy ways to get a word doc + fonts/layout into Illustrator, I'd be happy to hear 'em.

Thanks.

Comment: for clearance: I don't need the "_____" line, it's just there cause I was afraid my spaces might get truncated.

Comment: I found out that you can import .Docx (word 2007) files into Illustrator. It imports the tabs, but I have no idea how to recreate the effect. For example if I want to move it around, add new ones, ...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use tabs or columns to achieve that effect.

- **TABS**

  Open your Tabs palette using `Window -> Type -> Tabs (Ctrl + Shift + T)`

  [image: Illustrator Tabs]
- **COLUMNS**

  1. Create an area Text object add columns via `Type -> Area Type Options...`

  [image]
  [image]

Answer (score 2):

Use your tabs, then open the paragraph window and adjust the left indent. It will bring the start of the line in, but won't move the tab forward. Unfortunatley you can only do the the first tab.

[image: http://www.greenbugcreative.com/DEMO/tab1.jpg]
[image: http://www.greenbugcreative.com/DEMO/tab2.jpg]

Answer (score 1):

there is indeed a [right indent tab feature](http://www.peachpit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1761171&seqNum=7). the tab stop however needs to be set to an absolute value — so when you adjust the size of the text box you'll also need to modify the tab stop.

Comment: The main answer (how to do the tab) is in your given link. Now suppose the link is broken or the page has vanished.  Then your answer is useless for a reader. Please write by your own how to create such a tab.

Comment: thx kurt — you are right. i'll try to be a better StackExchange citizen. will update when i'll find the time.